# Why are my Karma unit tests throwing an error for missing value accessors in components that do not have any forms?

Tags: unit-testing, karma-jasmine, ionic4

I am setting up unit testing for our Ionic4 uni project (getting online help and research is an expected part of the project) and am having issues getting all the "create component" tests to pass in Karma. I have not written any tests myself, so am only trying to sort out all the errors thrown by the auto-generated ones.

The problem is that some components are throwing the following error: "Uncaught Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for form control with name: X", X being a form field in a completely different component (which tests are passing fine). This error only occurs if I run all tests. If I run specifically the ones that are failing, they will pass without problems.

I have tried researching the issue and error message, but so far have found nothing related to my specific issue. The problem is that there is no form in 2 of the 3 components that complain and in the 3rd, the complaints are about fields in another component.

This is the error message for the component Event:

```js
Uncaught Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'username'
    Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'username'
        at te (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js:2144 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:2092:1740)
        at J (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js:2054 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:2092:117)
        at webpack:///node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js:4337 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:2106:16703
        at e.invoke (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:2140:7006)
        at e.onInvoke (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:106 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:2290:1819)
        at e.onInvoke (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:126 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:2253:2259)
        at e.invoke (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:390 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:2140:6946)
        at Object.onInvoke (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:17299 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:600:1161)
        at e.invoke (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:390 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:2140:6946)
        at t.run (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:150 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:2140:2205)
        at webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:889 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:2140:13729
        at e.invokeTask (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:2140:7690)
        at e.onInvokeTask (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:90 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:2290:1616)
        at e.onInvokeTask (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:157 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:2253:2880)
        at e.invokeTask (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:422 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:2140:7611)
        at Object.onInvokeTask (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:304 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:2140:4663)
        at e.invokeTask (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:422 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:2140:7611)
        at Object.onInvokeTask (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:17290 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:600:1073)
        at e.invokeTask (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:422 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:2140:7611)
        at t.runTask (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:195 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:2140:2868)
        at v (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:601 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:2140:9981)
        at t.invokeTask [as invoke] (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:502 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:2140:8826)
        at y (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1744 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:2171:631)
        at g (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1770 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:2171:873) thrown
```

This is the .ts for Event:

```js
export class EventPage implements OnInit {
    activity: any;
    allEvents = [];

    constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService, private activityService: ActivityService, private dataService: DataService) {
    }


    ngOnInit() {
        this.activityService.getAllActivities().subscribe(data => this.allEvents = data);
        this.activity = 'all-activities';
    }

    loadEvent(activity) {
        this.dataService.setData('activity', activity);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/specific-event/activity');
    }

    goToCreateEvent() {
        this.router.navigate(['create-event']);
    }

    segmentChanged(event) {
        this.activity = event.target.value;
    }
}
```

The .spec.ts:

```js
import {CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';
import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';

import {EventPage} from './event.page';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {AuthService} from '../../services/authentication-service/auth.service';
import {ActivityService} from '../../services/activity-service/activity.service';
import {DataService} from '../../services/data.service';
import {SharedDirectivesModule} from '../../directives/shared-directives.module';
import {HasRoleDirective} from '../../directives/has-role.directive';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {UserService} from '../../services/user-service/user.service';
import {ActivityServiceMock, UserServiceMock} from '../../../../test-config/mocks-ionic';

describe('EventPage', () => {
    let component: EventPage;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<EventPage>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [SharedDirectivesModule],
            declarations: [EventPage],
            schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
            providers: [
                {provide: Router, useValue: null},
                {provide: AuthService, useValue: null},
                {provide: ActivityService, useValue: new ActivityServiceMock()},
                {provide: DataService, ueValue: null},
                {provide: UserService, useValue: new UserServiceMock()},
                {provide: TemplateRef, useValue: null},
                {provide: ViewContainerRef, useValue: null}]
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EventPage);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

And this is the form from the component Register, which does have the field being requested in Event:

```
   <form>
        ...
                        <ion-item>
                            <ion-input name="username" placeholder="Username" type="username" ngModel required
                                       [(ngModel)]="username"></ion-input>
                        </ion-item>

                        <ion-item>
                            <ion-input name="displayname" placeholder="Displayname" type="username" ngModel required
                                       [(ngModel)]="displayname"></ion-input>
                        </ion-item>

        ...
    </form>
```

Comment: I am not sure, but I hope you have `import`ed `FormModule` in `TestBed` of the test file. The error could be because the component which has `form` is being rendered while you are testing another component (which has this `form` component inside it , or under its children somewhere)

Comment: @ShashankVivek Thank you, I did try that at first without success. Turns out my issue was solved by adding ngDefaultControl to the complaining fields in the HTML - so it was a lack of understanding how the databinding works on my part.

Comment: Great. Please add this as an answer so that it can be helpful to others as well. Cheers mate!